# An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, group-by

I am stuck on retrieving results of this query. I am trying to find documents, where sum of qty corrected is more than qty in document related. I got error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT doc_Name
FROM DOCUMENTS
JOIN DOCUMENT_POSITIONS DP on docPos_DocId = doc_Id
WHERE SUM(docPos_Qty) > (SELECT docPos_Qty FROM DOCUMENT_POSITIONS WHERE docPos_Id = DP.docPos_RelatedDocPosId) 
AND doc_Type = 6 --CORRECTING DOCUMENT
```

Comment: Use HAVING clause for aggregate function conditions.

Comment: which database are you using and please add a full [mre]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT doc_Name
FROM DOCUMENTS
JOIN DOCUMENT_POSITIONS DP on docPos_DocId = doc_Id
AND doc_Type = 6 --CORRECTING DOCUMENT

GROUP BY doc_Name, DP.docPos_RelatedDocPosId
HAVING SUM(docPos_Qty) > (SELECT docPos_Qty FROM DOCUMENT_POSITIONS WHERE docPos_Id = DP.docPos_RelatedDocPosId)
```